# Can I add a second solar panel to a battery powered gate opener, to get more charging?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, solar-energy

The system is two 12 V batteries in series powering a 24 V motor.

Present 24 V solar panel is in parallel to the 24 V battery circuit.

Can I add a second 24 V panel in series or parallel, or should I replace the 24 V panel with two 12 V panels, one for each battery?

Do I need a special type of panel?

BACKGROUND

I have a Liftmaster sliding electric gate system with two 12 V batteries that in series provide 24 V to the controller board for the motor.

I added to one battery the gate's 12 V LED 24 W lights that operation 4 hours after sunset but the batteries run out of energy during cloudy times.  (I'm in northern California, normally tons of sun.)

Comment: If you put a load on one battery only, they will get unbalanced

Answer (score 1):

### Step 1: **Clean the solar panels**

*Simple, easy, you've probably already tried it.*

Wiping off the panel, even if it doesn't look dirty, can make a big difference.

### Step 2: Get a new set of batteries

*You probably only need to worry about this step.*

The batteries will wear out much sooner than the solar panels will and need to be replaced every few years. If you are getting plenty of power when the sun is out, then adding another solar panel will not make a difference, you need to store that power for later.

If you have enough room, and you are getting a lot of traffic when it is cloudy or dark, getting larger batteries will let you store more power. (Ex: Go from 2x 12V 1Ah batteries to 2x 12V 2Ah batteries.)

### Step 3: Get a charge controller

*If the issue comes back:*

Running a solar panel directly into a battery is pretty common for simple systems, but it will cause the battery to wear out more quickly. If you find that a new battery fixes the problem for a year or 2 and then it returns, invest in a charge controller to go between the solar panel and battery. This will regulate the power going to the battery and help it last longer.

Head on over to [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) if you need help finding one.

### Step 4: Add an additional 24V panel in parallel

*Do this last!*

If you find that the motor is struggling to put out enough power to move the gate even in full sun; or you have a really high amount of traffic, such that the gate is getting sluggish in the latter part of the day, the battery may be draining faster than the panel can recharge it. In this case, you can add a second 24V panel in **parallel**. I would not recommend doing this without a charge controller as you may push too much current into your battery, creating a fire hazard.

### Loads

*Using 12V loads*

Connecting a load to one battery only is a bad idea for the same reason as charging them separately. It will cause that battery's voltage to drop while the other's voltage stays the same. Charging unbalanced batteries in series will force current through the already charged battery. This will prevent the empty battery from getting fully charged, and damage the full battery. I have seen devices get away with this for **very** small currents (like a microcontroller), but this is bad for something like lights.

Get a regulator that can convert from 24V to 12V. That way you are pulling from both batteries. Many charge controllers have this built in, so you can run the motor directly from the batteries and the lights from the regulated 12V output of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't that the batteries are not getting charged, because your issue is only on cloudy days, after you added a continuous load. The led light is discharging one battery, and that's causing the set to go lower than the motors can start with. 24W isn't a small load you can just ignore.

Remove the light, and add a system just for it. Instead of trying to parallel a new solar panel on the existing system, use it and another battery for the led lights alone.

Alternatively, as @alphy13 has mentioned, use a regulator to get the lights powered from 24V. At the least it will draw power from both batteries equally so the drain is split between the two. (Or get 24V lights).